# merging git mingw64 installation with mingw-w64 installation

Tags: git, mingw, mingw-w64

When I compare the mingw64 folders from my git bash installation and my mingw-w64 installation, the executables in each are different. Is it possible to merge the two installation without any conflicts, or should I add the bin folder of both installation in my path environment variable?
Edit: by executables I mean the ones in the bin folder. For example, one folder has mingw32-make whereas the other doesn't

Comment: When the executables are different, the mingw versions are differrent. Why do you want to merge two versions of same product?

Comment: Sorry, didn't make it clear. Please see the edit

Comment: Sorry, didn't make it clear. Please see the edit

Comment: These are still of different versions, keep them apart.

Answer (score 1):

Don't mix up binary folder like that. You're bound to break stuff.
In particular .exe files depend on .dll files, and overwriting files with files from somewhere else could very well break the dependancy chain.

It's better to keep them in seperate locations that are both in the PATH environment variable. That way .exe dependancy .dll files will be looked for in the same folder as the .exe file, allowing .dll files with the same name but different versions to exist where needed.

However you should avoid making system-wide changes to the PATH environment variable. It's better to start the environment where you need it from a script (or batch file) so it sets the PATH as needed just for the purpose where you need it.

Comment: I would strongly recommend having neither in the system PATH.  Because the path is also used for runtime DLL search so it is all too easy to runtime-link to the wrong libraries leading to all sorts of problems.   Instead have a shell startup script (or batch file) that you open for each environment and it sets up variables for that window only .

Comment: How do you make this shell script? (I have no knowledge on these kind of scripts)

Comment: @AntPalmer check the Windows Command Prompt example on http://winlibs.com/ to get an idea on how to add to PATH from the prompt. The same commands can be used in a .bat file.